# Get Top 5 Values From Map

Tags: java

I have a map like so

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

This will be populated with a lot of entrys and what i am trying to do is make some kind of Top 5 stats.

What i have right now is

```
int maxValueInMap=(Collections.max(map.values()));
for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {                       
if (entry.getValue()==maxValueInMap) {
     name = entry.getKey();
}
}
```

Which works great for getting the key/value of the number 1 top highest value in the map but i can't figure out how i can get the top 5 highest and have something like

```
int maxValueInMap=(Collections.max(map.values()));
for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {                       
if (entry.getValue()==maxValueInMap) {
     name = entry.getKey();
     name2 = entry.getKey(2ndHighest);
     //so on
}
}
```

Would appreciate any help, thank you.

EDIT

I found this code which works like it want it to do

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    ValueComparator bvc =  new ValueComparator(map);
    TreeMap<String,Integer> sorted_map = new TreeMap<String,Integer>(bvc);

    map.put("a",10);
    map.put("b",6);
    map.put("c",6);
    map.put("d",56);
    map.put("e",54);
    map.put("f",32);
    map.put("g",1);

    System.out.println("unsorted map: "+map);
    sorted_map.putAll(map);
    System.out.println("results: "+sorted_map);
}
}

class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String> {

Map<String, Integer> base;
public ValueComparator(Map<String, Integer> base) {
    this.base = base;
}

public int compare(String a, String b) {
    if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b)) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
}
```

Which prints out

```
unsorted map: {a=10, b=6, c=6, d=56, e=54, f=32, g=1}
results: {d=56, e=54, f=32, a=10, c=6, b=6, g=1}
```

But how would i only get the top 5 from the sorted_map rather than all the entrys?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve only the top scores or also the associated keys ?

Comment: Yeah the keys aswel, i need to know which player is associated with which top score

Comment: @user3439600 - Sorry, but I felt it necessary to warn future readers of this question that the solution that you found is incorrect.  (Compare with what I said my answer to understand why ...).  Without a warning, people are liable to blindly copy-and-paste it into their own code, and get burned.  One could say with considerable justification that it "serves them right" ... but even so, we would not want to be indirectly responsible.

Comment: but i run the code and it works so how is it incorrect?

Comment: Edited OP, look at the results, the sorted_map prints each key correctly associated with its value, also prints out duplicate value so i am lost on why that is incorrect when thats exactly what i wanted

Comment: I see.  The Comparator is more subtle than I thought.  But even so, it is not incremental.  See happens if you call `put` on an existing key with a different count.  See what happens if you have multiple pairs with the same count (hint ... the comparator *violates* the contract!!).  Like I said ... you haven't tested it thoroughly!!

Comment: OTOH, if you don't need to be able to update the top 5 list incrementally, then the solution is a waste of time.  It would be more efficient to just sort the entry set for the `HashMap<String, Integer>`.

Comment: Every key is unique, i just showed you that it outputs the key/value of duplicate values

Comment: HashMap can't sort pairs by highest values

Comment: But is every count unique too?  Your problem statement doesn't mention that.

Comment: Do you mean "count" as in the value?

Comment: @user3439600 - but Arrays.sort() can.  Did you actually READ the first part of my answer???

Comment: Yes that is what I mean.  Aren't they counts??

Comment: And the array can keep both the key and value?

Comment: It will be an array of `Map<String, Integer>.Entry`.  So of course it can!

Comment: Can you show me an example of how that would be done? get the top 5 entrys from the map based on the highest values that would be better than what i have above

Comment: @user3439600 - Sorry, but aren't you a Java programmer?  You shouldn't need an example for something as simple as that.  Just code up the procedure I explained in the first part of my answer.  It is easy to the point of being trivial.  (And if it is not trivial for you, then doing it your self will make you a better Java programmer ... so get to it!!)

Comment: Well seing as i spent an hour looking on how to solve my OP and never once seen anyone mention it was as easy as putting it in an array i think ill just stick to what i got, thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You want to sort items by value, this can't be done by default in an `HashMap` nor a `TreeMap`.

You should consider having your own class and use a `TreeSet`:

```
class Entry implements Comparable<? extends Entry> {
  public final String name;
  public final Integer value;

  ..

  public int compareTo(Entry o) { return value == o.value ? o.name.compareTo(name) : o.value - value; }

  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    // equals consistent to compareTo (name and value equal for both entries)
  }
}

SortedSet<Entry> set = new TreeSet<Entry>();
set.add(...)
```

Comment: `value` should be of type `Integer`.

Comment: How would i get the keys/values from my original map from this?

Comment: I don't think this works.  See my answer for hints as to why.  For a start, that `compareTo` will result in "duplicates" being eliminated.

Comment: these are the results 

unsorted map: {a=10, b=6, c=6, d=56, e=54, f=32, g=1}
results: {d=56, e=54, f=32, a=10, c=6, b=6, g=1} duplicates are included

Comment: @StephenC: of course you must take care of having a correct natural ordering by using `if (o.value == value) return o.name.compareTo(name)`. That's obvious, but this method absolutely works.

Comment: @Jack - It works with the "obvious" fix that you have made ... but it still isn't incremental.  And unless the solution is incremental then it is better to copy the original HashMap's entry set to an array and sort it.

Comment: @StephenC Indeed it was obvious to me but when I wrote the answer it was incomplete (and even had String value). My point was related to the fact the this approach was pointed out as wrong while suggesting a different approach. But the approach works if correctly implemented. It's incremental as long there is no need to access values with keys (so that you don't need to have an HashMap at all)

Comment: Even using a separated array to be sorted on its own requires a compare function that takes into account the name if the values are equal and that is consistent with equals. Otherwise you would break the contract of the function itself, even if the result is correct (but you could get a different ordering for entries with the same value)

Answer (score 2):

The simple way to do this it:

- Copy the entry set of the hashmap to an array
- Sort the array
- Take the first 5 entries.

However, the sorting step is `O(N log N)`, and that is a performance killer if N is large and you need to get the top 5 repeatedly ... and the integer values (e.g. counts) can be updated.

---

If you need better performance you need more complicated data structures that allow *incremental* update (to avoid re-sorting):

- A 1 to 1 mapping from strings to string/count pairs
- An ordered collection of string/count pairs that is ordered on the counts

If you restrict yourself to standard collection classes, this can be done using the following:

- A custom `Pair` class to hold the pairs.
- A `HashMap<String, Pair>` for the forward mapping.
- A `TreeSet<Pair>` for keeping the pairs in order.
- A (stable) comparator that orders pairs primarily by count secondarily by `Pair` identity.  (The latter is important.  The comparator must not treat `Pair` objects with the same count as equal, or `Pair` objects will be incorrectly eliminated as duplicates!).

The final thing you remember is that the `TreeSet` will not automatically update properly if you just change the `count` in a `Pair`.  Instead, you need to:

1. Remove the `Pair` from the `TreeSet`
2. Update the `count`
3. Add the `Pair` back into the `TreeSet`.

The rest is "just programming".  (But too complicated for me to write, compile, test, etc right now :-) )

---

If you do the above correctly, then adding or incrementing a count should be `O(log N)` and finding the top 5 entries should be `O(1)`.  However, since you are using that as a replacement for a solution that had `O(1)` add / increment, this is only a clear performance win if `N` is large (enough) and "top 5" is a relatively common operation.

It is also worth noting that you can also get the top `M` elements in an unsorted collection of `N` elements in `O(N log M)`.  If `M` is a small constant, that reduces to `O(N)`.  In other words, it scales better than sorting the entry set in the simple version at the top.  (And it could be faster for small `N` too.)

---

In answer to this follow-up question:

> But how would i only get the top 5 from the sorted_map rather than all the entrys??

Create an iterator, and just call `next()` 5 times!

But I should also note that the code you have found is **INCORRECT**.  I strongly recommend that you code this for yourself and thoroughly test it.  (Or restrict your search to creditable libraries that include a decent unit test suite.)

Comment: But how would i keep the associated keys if i use the list for the values?

Comment: @user3439600 - Read the update.  (The answer is that you shouldn't do it that way.  Maintaining a simple list ordered by `count` will give you `O(N)` performance on insertion / update.)

Comment: @StephenC : do you really meant `HashMap<String,Pair>` rather than `HashMap<String,Integer>` ?

Comment: @StephenC : oh, yes, I get it now.